# Laravel: Generate URL to paginated item

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 to build a discussion forum. Each forum has threads, and each thread has replies. I can't find anything on how to get the URL of the latest reply to a thread - right now I have this function to show the forum:

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $forum = $this->forums->getBySlug($slug);
    return view('forum.show', compact('forum'));
}
```

Then in that view I have a basic `@forelse` to show the `HasMany` related threads:

```
@forelse($forum->threads as $thread)
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ route('forum.thread', [$forum->slug, $thread->slug]) }}">{{ $thread->title }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ $thread->replies->count() }} Replies</td>
        <td>{{ $thread->replies->last()->author->username or 'No recent activity' }}</td>
    </tr>
@empty
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="text-center">There aren't any threads in this forum</td>
    </tr>
@endforelse
```

This works fine, but I would like the username of the most recent reply to be linked to the actual reply with a url like `http://example.com/forum/thread-title-here/?page=3#12345` where the fragment is the reply ID. I can't figure it out, any ideas? I also get the error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate()` when using `$thread->replies->paginate(10)` to try and calculate the number of pages the thread has, but that brought up another issue regarding posts linked on other pages.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ran into a similar issue. Try this:

threads.model

```
// probably what you have now
public function replies() { return hasMany('Reply');}
```

You can add a second relation to the replies model like this:

```
// add this relation which has a filter
public function latestReply() { return hasOne('Reply')->last();}
```

Now when you want the latest reply, you can do this:

```
$forum = $this->forums->getBySlug($slug)->with('threads','threads.latestReply');
```

and in your view: 
`@foreach($forum->threads as $thread)
{{$thread->latestReply->id}}
@endforeach`

I learned this from [<strike>http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/</strike>](http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/)

[The original link no longer works. Click here to visit the Google cached version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?btnG=Search&q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fsoftonsofa.com%2Ftweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model%2F)

Hopefully I have translated this to your situation. You might want to review the link, it's more informative than I am.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was trying to do. Thanks for the link too!

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide enough code to give a detailed response, but for the sake of an example and assuming you use Laravel's naming conventions:

```
// Eager load threads and their replies
$forum = Forum::with(array('threads.replies' => function($q) {
    // For each thread, get the most recent reply
    $q->orderBy('some_date_column', 'desc')->take(1);
}))->get();
```

From the code you provided it seems that you would need to modify your getBySlug() method.